# How to connect 2 boards to a raspberry pi 3

Tags: power-management, hifiberry

I am building a home console stereo and I am going to use an RPi3 with a hifiberry dac+. And I am wondering if I can use a waveshare power relay to be able to control the power to the system from my phone. Is it possible to have two modules connected to one RPi or would I need to use 2 Pi's?

Here us a link to the power relay
http://www.waveshare.com/rpi-relay-board.htm

Comment: How exactly are you going to control the Pi with a relay and still be able to toggle the relay when the Pi is powered down via the relay?

Comment: I'm not going to power the pi with it. Just accessories like the amplifier and turntable and stuff.

Comment: Does the answer help you? if so, please accept it with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the two boards do not use the same pins (they can share the I2C and SPI bus pins - if using SPI each board will need a unique slave select pin.). You could use the [Black Hat Hack3r Board](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3182?gclid=Cj0KEQjw4cLKBRCZmNTvyovvj-4BEiQAl_sgQvZf-7rVcCFkksNzF1_VaIT-GS9YHP5BxoyouZeOI-8aAg9R8P8HAQ). To access the GPIO pins while still using a HAT.

[image: Black hat hack3r Board]

**Note:** if both boards fully conform to the hat standard (use an eprom to identify and configure the HAT's hardware) they will not work together, even with this board.

If you can not connect both boards to a single Pi, using a second Pi is a good option. But a Pi2 is overkill if all you want to do is switch the power on/off via a relay (a Pi Zero W is more than capable of this and much cheaper).

Comment: They are both stackable could I not just stack them?

Comment: That might have been an important point to make in your question. As the old adage goes a picture is worth a thousand words. Assuming they don't share any pins as stated above you should be OK. Note if they both conform to the HAT standard and have an eprom you will not be able to use them together, with or without the board I mentioned.